# How do I access this Variable outside the function

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli, var

```
function GetActiveWeek($mysqli, $ActiveWeekEndingDate) {
    $stmt = "SELECT ParameterValue FROM INF_WebConfig WHERE ParameterName = 'ActiveWeekEndingDate'";
    $ActiveWeekEndingDate = $mysqli->query($stmt);
    return $ActiveWeekEndingDate;
}
```

I need to echo $ActiveWeekEndingDate elsewhere how do I access this outside of the function correctly.

EDIT:

I managed to get it working with the Following but it isn't really nessicary to prepare the statement is it?

```
function GetActiveWeek($mysqli) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ParameterValue FROM INF_WebConfig WHERE ParameterName = 'ActiveWeekEndingDate'"); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($ActiveWeekEndingDate);
    $stmt -> fetch();
    $stmt -> close();
    $mysqli -> close();
    return $ActiveWeekEndingDate;
}
```

Comment: Just call the function and it will return $ActiveWeekEndingDate. echo GetActiveWeek($mysqli, $ActiveWeekEndingDate);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function GetActiveWeek($mysqli) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ParameterValue FROM INF_WebConfig WHERE ParameterName = 'ActiveWeekEndingDate'"); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($ActiveWeekEndingDate);
    $stmt -> fetch();
    $stmt -> close();
    $mysqli -> close();
    return $ActiveWeekEndingDate;
}
```

This was how i achieved the result. I just call the function where the variable is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Why not handle it in the response?

```
$ActiveWeekEndingDate = GetActiveWeek();
echo $ActiveWeekEndingDate;
```

If you insist on having it global (discouraged), add this above the function:

```
global $ActiveWeekEndingDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the return value from the GetActiveWeek function to a variable you can access out of the function.

```
function GetActiveWeek($mysqli, $ActiveWeekEndingDate) {
        $stmt = "SELECT ParameterValue FROM INF_WebConfig WHERE ParameterName = 'ActiveWeekEndingDate'";
        $ActiveWeekEndingDate = $mysqli->query($stmt);
        return $ActiveWeekEndingDate;
}

$retVal = GetActiveWeek($mysqli, $ActiveWeekEndingDate);
```